# how to set UIFont bold in iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel

I  want to set the font of `UILabel` to **helvetica bold** but **it just shows normal font.**

I am using below code

```
UILabel *labelHeadingOne = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22,260, 504, 20)];
labelHeadingOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

labelHeadingOne.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

labelHeadingOne.text=@"Pre-emergent herbicide with residual control for warm-season turf";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the font name `Helvetica-Bold`.  Check out http://iosfonts.com/ for the full list.

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
  labelHeadingOne.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this;

```
[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
```